# Invalid handle passed to midiInClose

Tags: delphi

Below I have some code. What I want to happen is when a button is pressed it creates, or closes, a MIDI connection depending on the state of an existing connection.

But, when attempting to close the MIDI handle I get an error response code 5, which means an invalid handle to a MIDI device has been passed to `midiInClose`.

I'm not sure why this is happening by my guess is scope issues? I just can't figure out how to resolve this. Should the `hMidiIn` be defined as a class variable within the form?

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.UITypes, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  MMSystem, uMIDI;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    MidiInputCombo: TComboBox;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;
  IsConnected: Boolean = False;
  SelectedMidiInputID: Integer = 0;
  hMidiIn: PHMIDIIN;
implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure MidiInProc(hmi: PHMIDIIN; wMsg: UINT; dwInstance: DWORD_PTR; dwParam1: DWORD_PTR; dwParam2: DWORD_PTR); stdcall;
begin
  // Do something
end;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MidiInCloseResult: Integer;
begin
  if IsConnected then
    begin
      MidiInCloseResult :=  midiInClose(hMidiIn^);
      if MidiInCloseResult = MMSYSERR_NOERROR then
        begin
          IsConnected := False;
          Button1.Caption := 'Connect';
        end
      else
        MessageDlg('Response: ' + IntToStr(MidiInCloseResult), mtInformation, [mbOk], 0, mbOk);
    end
  else
    if midiInOpen(@hMidiIn, SelectedMidiInputID, DWORD_PTR(@MidiInProc), 0, CALLBACK_FUNCTION) = MMSYSERR_NOERROR then
      begin
        IsConnected := True;
        Button1.Caption := 'Disconnect';
      end;
end;

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  DevCount: Integer;
  Pmic: MIDIINCAPS;
begin
  DevCount := MidiInputDeviceCount();

  if DevCount > 0 then
    for I := 0 to DevCount do
       midiInGetDevCaps(I, @Pmic, SizeOf(pmic));
       MidiInputCombo.Items.Add(Pmic.szPname);

    MidiInputCombo.ItemIndex := SelectedMidiInputID;
end;

end.
```

Comment: hMidiIn needs to point somewhere, or be a HMIDIIN structure, so you have a naming conflict straight away. I suggest using the structure (not the pointer) when both the open and close should take @ form. The ^ form is definitely wrong.

Comment: @Dsm thanks. I was thinking because `PHMIDIIN` was a pointer that it needed dereferencing to `HMIDIIN`. The midi open function returns `PHMIDIIN`. I'm a little confused.

Comment: Re confused - well lets us say you called what you currently call hMidiIn something like MyMidiIn of type HMidiIn (var MyMidiIn : hMidiIn;) then @MyMidiIn is of type PHMIDIIN. You have called your variable (which is a pointer) the same as the record type and therefore hide the record type. That is what I meant by a naming conflict. Hope that makes sense...

Comment: You're not getting the handle in the first place: `midiInOpen(@hMidiIn, ...` hMidiIn is a pointer, you're passing the address of a pointer. Naming creates confusion, if you're declaring a pointer name it PMidiIn - or something like that. As Dsm tells, rather use the struct as global, not a pointer. `hMidiIn: HMIDIIN`. Then pass it's address to pass a pointer to midiInOpen, as you already do. After that, you won't have to dereference anything when calling midiInClose.

Comment: The first part of the first sentence of @Dsm's first comment is crucial. Declaring a pointer does not magically create the space where it points to.

Comment: Turn on [Type-checked pointers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Type-checked_pointers_(Delphi)) and you should get a compiler error on the `midiInOpen()` call due to the incorrect declaration of the `hMidiIn` variable.

Comment: Thanks a lot folks for helping clear the confusion. I completely forgot about case sensitivity and didn't realize `hMidiIn` as being the same as `HMIDIIN`.